# find a .txt file and write in it

Tags: linux, shell, find

I was wondering if it is possible to find multiple .txt files in a directory and its sub-directories and write something in it. something like

```
find . -depth -type d -path "/path/to/files/*.txt" -exec echo > *.txt;
```

I managed to create the files like this but now I would like to write in all of them.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you find a txt file what do you want to do with that is not so clear.

Comment: @abhijitPritam edited my post, thank you didnt notice

Comment: What is `touch > file` supposed to do?!

Comment: @GéCusters I *think* what you're looking for is something like `find /path/to/files/ -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'something > "{}"'`, but the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Biffen I edited my post it was supposed to be `echo > file` It doesnt exist as fas as i know but i would like to do something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to answer with an example:

To write 'blablubb' to each file (and subdirectories) in:

```
me@my:/tmp$ ls /tmp/*txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 v v  9 Mar  7 13:24 /tmp/0txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 v v  9 Mar  7 13:24 /tmp/1txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 v v  9 Mar  7 13:24 /tmp/2txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 v v  9 Mar  7 13:24 /tmp/3txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 v v  9 Mar  7 13:24 /tmp/4txt
```

You can write wtih `find ... -exec ...` **or** `xargs`:

```
me@my:/tmp$ find . -maxdepth 2 -regex '.*txt' | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo 'blablubb' >> {}" 

me@my:/tmp$ find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*txt' -exec cat {} \;
blablubb
blablubb
blablubb
blablubb
blablubb
```

more can be find here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22229/xargs-with-stdin-stdout-redirection

Comment: thanks for your help I'll try it and let you know if it worked or if I managed to  get it working